# What to do with slow b2c new user emails

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there a b2c sign-up email slow-down today? Taking forever to get email verification ids. Lagging 20+ minutes to deliver, by which time the code has expired.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if your question isn't going to be of any interest to a single person in a few days then it doesn't belong on this site.

Comment: Agreed @DrEval -- though I was instructed to post here via twitter. Not my usual thing to spam.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure, there is no SLA on email delivery. Could be an transient issue as well. As Micah suggested you can post your query in MSDN forum.